# Google Analytics in android underreporting events

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to record image views and clicks on one of the activities. I call the click event from onResume, and not in onCreate, so that the image views can be recorded every time the user comes back to that Activity.

```
Tracker tracker = getApplication()
                .getTracker(xxxxx);
            tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                .setCategory("Category")
                .setAction("view")
                .setLabel("label")
                .build());
```

But the events being recorded are around 50% of the total sessions on Google Analytics. The events being recorded are on the very first screen of the app, which starts a new session. I expect at least one event per session, but the events recorded are far less than the sessions.

I am not doing any sampling.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what count be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You should send other hits to start your session. How do you send them? Do you have automatic activity tracking enabled?

Comment: Yes, automatic activity tracking is enabled. I don't start the session manually.

Comment: Are you using the default session duration of 30 minutes? With the default session duration inactivity of 30 minutes starts a new session. Inactivity is defined as absence of interactive hits. Are you sending any other hits in addition to the screen view hits (send by the automatic activity tracking) and the explicit event you send from onResume?
 Also not all API levels of android support automatic activity tracking. If your app is running on API 11 or earlier automatic activity tracking will not work. You need to explicitly call GoogleAnalytics.reportActivityStart(activity).